# How specyfic sender for encryptions gpg

Tags: gnupg

I need encrypt a file. In my keychains I have many private keys. How can I specify which key to use to encrypt a file?

```
gpg -e --armor -r to_who  file.txt
```

and how check, this is true (I have my own private key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the option: -u

```
gpg -e -u my_key -r to_key file.txt
```